# Drupal : Display nodes that are part of relationship too

Tags: drupal

I am trying to create a website which can store family information. I have a created a contact node type using cck which store family records such as name, birthday etc.

Currently I have four records Indu , Krishna and Sudarshan,Anirudha I have created three relationships Krishna isfatherof Sudarshan, so automatically Sudarshan issonof Krishna Indu isMotherof Sudarshan, so automatically Sudarshan issonof Indu Indu isWifeof Krishna, so automatically Krishna isHusbandof Indu

Now I have created a filter using FirstName field(which is part of contact node).

Now what I want is when I search for FirstName such as Krishna , it should not only display the record Krishna but also all nodes with whom Krishna is in relation with.

So, if I search for Krishna it should display Krishna

but also should display Indu and Sudarshan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to related 2 content types in one of them you should add node reference field and set it to reference other type. Then when you make objects in those types, with type that has node reference field you'll have a list of related objects (or just node ids, so you have to load them manually with node_load(), can't remember). And for other you should use views module to get related nodes.

Comment: I have tried using views but in vain.Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Google for it - there are many views related tutorials. I,.e.: http://www.acquia.com/blog/totally-beginner-tutorial-views-drupal-7

Comment: I know how to use views but do not know how to use views with relationship

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to do it.Its pretty simple.
Create a new view of content type and add all these relations by using Advanced -> Relationships
Krishna isfatherof Sudarshan,Sudarshan issonof Indu Indu isWifeof Krishna, 
Now add Fields in View
Content:Title
Content:Title(Relationship isFatherof)
Content:Title(Relationship isMotherof)
Content:Title(Relationship isSonof)

This should work